# Child[] can not be passed to a method accepting Parent[]. Why?

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism

Why am I getting compilation error on passing Child[] into a method accepting Parent[] ?

However I can define a variable of Parent[] and assign it a value Child[].

Kathy Sierra Book Generics chapter says it should work fine.

```
package com.collections;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class AnimalDoctor{
    public void checkAnimals(Animal[] animals){
        for(Animal a: animals){
            a.check();          
        }
    }
}
abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void check();
}
class Dog {
    public void check(){
        System.out.println(" Check Dog");
    }
}
class Cat {
    public void check(){
        System.out.println(" Check Cat");
    }
}
class Bird {
    public void check(){
        System.out.println(" Check Bird");
    }
}

public class TestGenerics {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        class Parent{}
        class Child extends Parent{}
        Parent[] array = new Child[11];                 //no error in assigning array of child elements to Parent[]

        Dog[] dogs = { new Dog(), new Dog()};
        Cat[] cats = { new Cat(), new Cat(), new Cat()};
        Bird[] birds = {new Bird()};

        AnimalDoctor doctor = new AnimalDoctor();
        doctor.checkAnimals(dogs);      //compilation error - why?
        doctor.checkAnimals(cats);      //compilation error - why?
        doctor.checkAnimals(birds);     //compilation error - why?
    }
}
```

Comment: Classes Cat, Dog and Bird should extend the Animal class.

Answer (score 1):

My `Dog`, `Cat`, and `Bird` classes were missing `extends Animal`.